# (django) get query of child class

Tags: django, inheritance, python-object

I have a super class like this:

```
class Superclass(models.Model):
 number = models.PositiveIntegerField()

 class Meta:
  abstract = True

 def get_next(self):
  return Superclass.objects.get(number=self.number+1)
```

Now, I have a child class that inherits from the superclass.

What's the problem?

1. I can't do this: `Superclass.objects` because the superclass doesn't refer to any database table.
2. I don't want to query *all* Superclass childs, only the one of the current child class, like this: When I do `instance_of_child1.get_next` I don't want to get an instance of `Child2`.

How to solve this?

- My first idea was to add a static constant to any child class that contains the class (So I could do `self.myclass.objects`) But this seems to be not a good way.
- Make the method `get_next` being part of the child class. Problem: there will be duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def get_next(self):
    return self.__class__.objects.get(number=self.number+1)
```

Comment: I made it by `type(self).objects`, but I think, that's the same.